# Parentheses in postfix notation expression

Tags: algorithm, postfix-notation

I've got exercise where I need to write a calculataor which evaluates expression in **postfix notation**. The problem is that this calculator had to handle parenthesis in this notation. In almost all sources I found algorithms for that notation don't include parentheses.

The question is how to cope with the **postfix expression** that contains parenthesis. I'm going to use algorithm based on stack. Is it correct to just deal with it like in infix notation?

Here is the examplary expression in **prefix** notation that contains parenthesis

```
- (/(: max-.5 -3 (^7 8.01) .141592654 10) ^10 5) 0.878074901849378
```

Comment: What's the meaning of parentheses in your postfix expression? In the prefix example you gave, looks like you can safely ignore them (treat them like a whitespace).

Comment: (You might pretend that operators that are basically defined for two operands and associative can be "trivially" extended to *n* operands. There, I see use for *opening* parentheses - no idea what use closing parenthesis would be, and more than one where to place (and ignore…) them.)

Comment: @greybeard: i suppose the close paren always follows an operator. Perhaps it is appropriate to think of it as a kind of dereferencing postfix operator whose effect is to transform a symbol (say, "max") into a corresponding executable value, and then apply it to the arguments. "max" not followed by a close paren might be an error or it might signify something else, or it might be the executable value itself, as a higher-order object.

Comment: There are no parentheses in postfix notation. That is its whole point. Your question is unclear if not meaningless.